# How to display new lines in Chrome development tools network preview tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I seem to have inadvertently toggled a setting somewhere with the result that the `Network > Preview` tab in Chrome's developer tools no longer displays new lines in responses containing, say, the contents of PHP's `var_dump()`. New lines are displayed however when using Firefox. I'm using Chrome **61.0.3163.100**.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
var_dump((object)[
    'bar' => 123,
    'baz' => 'test'
]);
```

**Whose output is displayed in Chrome's `Network > Preview` tab:**

[image: Chrome Output]

**How can I change Chrome's settings so that the output is displayed with new lines, like with Firefox:**

[image: Firefox Output]

Comment: https://crbug.com/767393 - this is fixed in Chrome Canary which you can install separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this instead the var_dump():

```
function dda($item = null, $live = null, $multiple = false){
    $debug = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($debug as $value){
        if($value['function'] == 'dda'){
            $location = $value['file'].' - '.$value['line'];
            echo $location;
            echo PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($multiple && is_array($item)){
        foreach($item as $value) echo var_export($value);
    }else{
        echo var_export($item);
    }

    if(!$live) die();
}
```